# Character limit on html select option?

Tags: html

I'm developing a screen where I have a html select element. The options are dynamically populated. The problem is, there is an option (a description) which contains 1000 characters in it! When I populate this, there are no errors. When the user interacts with the select, the browser (Firefox) crashes and gets force closed. Can any one tell me whether there is a character limit for an html select option, either in the actual standards, or in actual implementation practice?

Comment: what browser? Every single one out there?

Comment: I checked on firefox.

Comment: Is it import to contain all the thousand characters in the selection element? This seems to be bad idea. Perhaps you should add the substring (front part of the string) and display the full text in different view like tooltip.

Comment: what interaction is done? created an example <option value ="test">1000chars</option> is working fine

Comment: Do 1,000 characters actually fit on the screen width wise in a select box anyway?  If they don't, then what's the point?  Try giving a shortened version then populating programmatically afterward.

Comment: it's important to show the entire string! it'a actually a spring + java web application. runs on firefox..

Comment: A [small, self-contained example](http://sscce.org/) would be a valuable addition to your question.  Like @MatthiasG noted, your problem is not reproducible with the information you have posted.

Comment: Indeed. I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HGwbr/) with not just 1000 chars in the content, but also 1000 chars in the _value_ of the option, and it submits just fine. So it must be something the OP didn't mention.